# Inserting into aspnetuser and insert some values to another table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, dbcontext

I am trying to insert a value from the standard MVC registration form (namely the email field), this will be the primary key and FK in another table. My student table only contains email, I want to insert the same value(email field) that is submitted at registration to the aspnetusers table. I have written this code so far:

```
var student = new Student { email = model.Email };
```

assigning the value and then

```
db.Students.Add(student);
db.SaveChanges();
```

to perform the action, I assume this is done in the Registration controller. Please advise if I have placed it in the wrong section. I am currently getting a

Please see code below:

AccountController.cs

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
            var student = new Student { email = model.Email };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {

                string callbackUrl = await SendEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account");


                ViewBag.Message = "Check your email and confirm your account, you must be confirmed "
                                + "before you can log in.";
                db.Students.Add(student);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return View("Info");

                //return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

Student.cs

```
 public class Student
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("User")]
    public string email { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I don't see you do `student.User = ` anywhere.

Comment: Also try reading [Primary and Foreign Key Constraints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms179610.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your foreign key here is on the implicit table colum `User_Id`, which is non-nullable by default, and you've not set a value for `User` to get the value from. It seems like you're wanting to use the email as the foreign key, instead, but that's not how things work. A foreign key references the primary key of the related table, which for `AspNetUsers` is `Id`, *not* `Email`. Even if you *could* do it this way, it would be an extremely bad idea. `Email` is NVARCHAR(MAX), which cannot be indexed.

Long and short, the quick fix is to simply set `User` on your student instance:

```
var student = new Student { email = model.Email, User = user };
```

However, it would be far better to implement inheritance here. A student is a user, so set it up that way:

```
public class Student : ApplicationUser
```

Then, you don't need any of this at all. By creating a `Student` there's automatically an associated `ApplicationUser`, because it *is* an `ApplicationUser`.

**UPDATE**

When inheriting, just remember that you're inheriting all the properties on `ApplicationUser`, so you don't need to add `Email` and such again. If you pull the user from the context, you can use `OfType<Student>`, for example, to only get students. If you use the default implementation of `ApplicationUserManager`, it will always return `ApplicationUser` instances, though. However, since it inherits from `UserManager<TUser>`, you can simply modify that class to remain generic:

```
public class ApplicationUserManager<TUser> : UserManager<TUser>
    where TUser : ApplicationUser
```

To avoid having to modify any existing code, you can declare a non-generic version of the class as well:

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : ApplicationUserManager<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationUserManager(UserStore<ApplicationUser> store)
        : base(store)
    {
    }
}
```

Then, you can construct different instances of `ApplicationUserManager` to work with the different types of users you have. Since `ApplicationUser` is your base type, you should use that if you need to work with *all* users, such as for the purposes of general sign in.

Comment: I tried the quick fix and it did not work, gave an error Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details. when it reached
 
    db.SaveChanges();, 

I am more interested in the inheritance way thou, after doing 

    public class Student : ApplicationUser

 will I need to change anything else?

Comment: Also I would like to be when someone registers based on their email it determines if they are a student or a lecturer, hence why I was taking that approach. Is that possible with going ahead with inheritance?

Comment: Thanks Chris, I will give that a go and if I have too much problem, I think I might take another approach by removing the relationship between aspnetusers and students with the foreign key constraint. I will then place the email field insertion into the student table after the results have been successful and enters into that IF statement block, I will perform the action there. That will also get the same job done that I want.

Answer (score 0):

If student.email is a FK,then email must be exist in db in order to add new student

Answer (score 0):

Student.cs is not correct.
Foreign key points to a PRIMARY KEY in another table.

You can edit Student.cs like this:

```
public class Student
{
    [Key]
    public int StudentId { get; set; }

    //Foreign key for User
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
```

and if email is unique check it on the user table when register like this:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
     var checkEMail = db.AspNetUsers.Where(a=>a.Email == model.Email).FirstOrDefault();
     if(checkEMail != null)
      {
           //Email is not valid
      }
     else
     {              
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
            var student = new Student { email = model.Email };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {

                string callbackUrl = await SendEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account");


                ViewBag.Message = "Check your email and confirm your account, you must be confirmed "
                                + "before you can log in.";
                db.Students.Add(student);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return View("Info");

                //return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            AddErrors(result);
      }

}
```